# In JavaScript How to check array values exists in array of object without duplication

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an array

```
let names = ['Devid', 'Aries','James'];
```

and an array of object

```
let details = [
{"Name":"John"},
{"Name":"Devid"},
{"Name":"Aries"},
{"Name":"Aries"}
];
```

I want to check all names exist in detail also they are not duplicate by name in 1 loop
If duplicate values exist then count it as 1
Output should be count= 2 but my code is returning count 3

```
 let names = ['Devid', 'Aries','James'];

 let details = [
    {"Name":"John"},
    {"Name":"Devid"},
    {"Name":"Aries"},
    {"Name":"Aries"}
    ];

let count = 0;

for (var eachDetail of details) {
     // checking here Name exist
     let isNameFound = names.some(el => eachDetail.Name.includes(el));
            if (isNameFound) count++;
        }
console.log(count);

// console.log(3) expected output 2
```

> Output Should be 2 (As Devid and Aries) exist

Comment: For each name, filter the array for elements with matching name and verify that the length of the filtered array is 1.

Comment: So what is the expected output....

Comment: Output Should be 2 (As Devid and Aries) exist

Comment: Are duplicates possible in the array?

Comment: no if duplicates exist count it as 1

Comment: I have added proper code and expected outpt

Comment: @Kainat See my answer below. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply iterate over the `names` array and perform a `details.find(...)` operation. If you find the object in `details`, add it to the resulting list.

```js
let names = ['Devid', 'Aries','James'];

let details = [
  {"Name":"John"},
  {"Name":"Devid"},
  {"Name":"Aries"},
  {"Name":"Aries"}
];

let result = [];
names.forEach(name => {
  const object = details.find(detail => detail.Name === name);
  if (object) {
    result.push(object);
  }
});

console.log(result.length + ' entries found:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to count the elements in the array that can be found in the object's values. You can use a `Set` to remove duplicates.

```js
let names = ['Devid', 'Aries','James'];

let details = [
  {"Name":"John"},
  {"Name":"Devid"},
  {"Name":"Aries"},
  {"Name":"Aries"}
];

const detailsNames = [...new Set(details.map(d => d.Name))];
const count = [...new Set(names)].reduce((acc, el) => acc + detailsNames.includes(el), 0);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to filter the array using `.filter()`, with also a `.some()` and `.inlcude()` methods inside verifying nonduplicates.

Please see documentation on JS Array methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```js
let names = ['Devid', 'Aries','James'];
let tempNames = [];

let details = [
  {"Name":"John"},
  {"Name":"Devid"},
  {"Name":"Aries"},
  {"Name":"Aries"}
];

var newDetails = details.filter(x => {
    let includeName = names.some(j => j == x.Name) && !tempNames.includes(x.Name);
    tempNames.push(x.Name);
    return includeName;
});

console.log(newDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prototype Array, then loop through names array

```js
Array.prototype._indexOfName = function(name){
  let n = 0;
  for(; n < this.length; n++)
    if(this[n].Name == name)
      return n
  return -1
};

let names = ['Devid', 'Aries','James'];
let details = [
  {"Name":"John","Age":20},
  {"Name":"Devid","Age":23},
  {"Name":"Aries","Age":34},
  {"Name":"Aries","Age":50}
];
let n = 0;
let n2 = 0;
for(; n < names.length; n++)
  if(details._indexOfName(names[n]) > -1)
    n2 ++
alert('Found ' + n2 + ' matches')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions that [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `names` array based on presence in `details`. Then retrieve the length of the filtered array.

One way of checking the presence of a name in `details` would be to use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Which returns `true` as soon as the return value of the callback is truthy.

Another way of doing this would be to place all the names of the `details` in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) first. Which allows you to simplify the filter callback to `name => detailNames.has(name)`.

```js
const names = ["Devid", "Aries", "James"];
const details = [
  { "Name": "John"  },
  { "Name": "Devid" },
  { "Name": "Aries" },
  { "Name": "Aries" },
];

// solution #1
const count1 = names.filter((name) => (
  details.some(detail => detail.Name == name)
)).length;
console.log(count1);

// solution #2
const detailNames = new Set(details.map(detail => detail.Name));
const count2 = names.filter(name => detailNames.has(name)).length;
console.log(count2);
```

Both solutions assume that `names` doesn't contain duplicate names.

The first solution is most likely faster if `details` is small. The second solution has some more overhead, but is faster if `details` is large. This is due to the fact that `some()` starts iterating from start to end searching for an item, while `has()` uses a lookup algorithm.